# Wordpress custom Password recovery usando ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

he usado el siguiente código para crear un formulario personalizado para recuperar la contraseña de wordpress vía e-mail sin tener que pasar por el formulario propio de wordpress, aquí este el código
-PHp-

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $error = '';
    $success = '';


    if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && 'reset' == $_POST['action'] ) 
    {
        $email = trim($_POST['user_login']);

        if( empty( $email ) ) {
            $error = 'Enter a username or e-mail address..';
        } else if( ! is_email( $email )) {
            $error = 'Invalid username or e-mail address.';
        } else if( ! email_exists( $email ) ) {
            $error = 'There is no user registered with that email address.';
        } else {

            $random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
            $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

            $update_user = wp_update_user( array (
                    'ID' => $user->ID, 
                    'user_pass' => $random_password
                )
            );


            if( $update_user ) {
                $to = $email;
                $subject = 'Your new password';
                $sender = get_option('name');

                $message = 'Your new password is: '.$random_password;

                $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
                $headers[] = 'From: '.$sender.' < '.$email.'>' . "\r\n";

                $mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                if( $mail )
                    $success = 'Check your email address for you new password.';

            } else {
                $error = 'Oops something went wrong updaing your account.';
            }

        }

        if( ! empty( $error ) )
            echo '<div class="message"><p class="error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> '. $error .'</p></div>';

        if( ! empty( $success ) )
            echo '<div class="error_login"><p class="success">'. $success .'</p></div>';
    }
?>
```

-HTML-

```
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.</p>
            <p><label for="user_login">Username or E-mail:</label>
                <?php $user_login = isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ? $_POST['user_login'] : ''; ?>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php echo $user_login; ?>" /></p>
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
                <input type="submit" value="Get New Password" class="button" id="submit" />
            </p>
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

Esta funcional, pero el problema biene cuando uso un include para añadir esto a una pagina, por que uso javascript para crear ventanas de login, registro y contraseña olvidada.
Cuando se usa el botón de submit para recuperar la contraseña, la web carga y en vez de ver el mensaje php, la web carga de nuevo y vuelves al apartado de login sin poder ver si has colocado un email correcto o no, y quiero hacerlo por **ajax**, el problema es que no tengo ni idea de como. Alguien me podría orientar?
Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

al final con calma, y leyendo un poco, he logrado que funcion de la siguiente manera.

```
var registerbutton = $('#submit');
registerbutton.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user_login = $('#user_login').val();
    var data = {
        user_login: user_login,
        action: 'reset'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Password/password-recovery.php",
        data: data
    })
        .done(function (msg) {
            $("#result").html(msg);
        });
});
```

Lo dejo posteado por si a alguien le hace falta.